# How to prevent dojo.dnd.moveable to make input fields disable

Tags: dojo-dnd

I use dojo.dnd.Moveable for making DIVs drag-able & drop-able in the page (Something like iGoogle). But the problem is after making them moveable, all of input fields (like text-boxes and list-boxes) will be disable and I can not write any thing in text fields or select any item from list-boxes!

What should I do with that?

Tnx
/Goli

Answer (score 0):

It fixed!

var m = new dojo.dnd.Moveable(gadget, {skip: true});